# How to install older version of pytorch

Tags: python, pip, pytorch

Following this https://pytorch.org/get-started/previous-versions/#via-pip

```
pip install torch==0.2.0_4 -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cpu/stable
Collecting torch==0.2.0_4
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement torch==0.2.0_4 (from versions: 0.1.2, 0.1.2.post1, 0.3.1, 0.4.0, 0.4.1, 1.0.0, 1.0.1, 1.0.1.post2, 1.1.0)
No matching distribution found for torch==0.2.0_4
```

How to install older version of pytorch?

Comment: https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/how-to-switch-to-older-version-of-pytorch/19656

Comment: did you try: `conda install pytorch==1.7.1 torchvision cudatoolkit=10.2 -c pytorch`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
pip install torch==

Collecting torch==
```

> ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement torch== (from versions: 0.1.2, 0.1.2.post1, 0.4.1, 1.0.0, 1.0.1, 1.0.1.post2, 1.1.0)
>       ERROR: No matching distribution found for torch==

This means that version 0.2 is not available

You can download the specific version ([wheels](https://pytorch.org/get-started/previous-versions/) seem available) and install it with `pip install`

Comment: How to install suitable `torchvision` version? `pip install torchvision` installs some other pytorch version over version installed by whl.

Comment: Not sure to have understood. Anyway, the best is to create a virtuaenv and install the versions you require for each package in order not to have conflicts.

Comment: For my case it seems `pip install torchvision==0.2.0 --no-deps --no-cache-dir`

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
conda install pytorch==1.7.1 torchvision cudatoolkit=10.2 -c pytorch
```

note I also specified the cuda version too.

Note this was asked on the pytorch forum too: https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/how-to-switch-to-older-version-of-pytorch/19656/21